# Select One of the Child Elements from Siblings with Same Name using XSL/XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes, element, xslt-2.0

I have a very basic question. I need to select only one child element in the xml using xslt, but I cannot find the correct xpath to identify the child I need.

Input XML:

```
<root>
    <land>
        USA
    </land>
    <child>
        Sam
    </child>
    <child>
        John
        <child2>
            Smith
        </child2>
        <child2>
            Elton
        </child2>
        <child2>
            Elway
        </child2>
    </child>
    <child>
        Charlie
    </child>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

```
<extraction>
Elway
</extraction>
```

Could anyone help me with this in xslt? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: You need to explain the logic that should be applied here. What is the criterion that makes `Elway` special?

Comment: `/root/child/child2[last()]` would be one path for that sample input but it would of course select any "last" `child2` for other `child` elements if they had them. So if it is based on the `child` value then perhaps `/root/child[normalize-space(text()) = 'John']/child2[last()]` is more that you are looking for.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's just an example. There is nothing special about it other than having to path a child element that has similar names with its siblings

Comment: @MartinHonnen your answers is perfect! It is exactly what I was looking for. I think there are many ways to path that I even figured out how to path specifically like doing /root/child/child2[3]. Your method is much better! Thanks so much!

Comment: @ChrisUdu If you want the **last** `child2` you should say so. Otherwise we might think you want the one that contains "w". Or any other random property.

Comment: @michael.hor257k my bad! I can see how that is vague. I should be more clear next time. Thanks for your help anyway!